# How to assert a String<Optional> in java without asserting an Optional<optional>?

Tags: java, junit

I'm making a JUnit test case that returns a string. However I keep getting this error:

[expected: java.util.Optional but was java.lang.String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9PB6.png)

`expected java.util.Optional<Optional> but was java.lang.String<Optional>`

and when I try to expect a string I just get

`expected <9999999.0000> but was <Optional[9999999]>`

(Yes, the string returned is the number 9999999 and not an integer.)

I've looked up how to use String all i can and i keep getting information about the java.util.Optional versions, nothing pops up about what I actually need. Not only that, there are tons of other tests in my project that just compare strings normally. Using

`assertEquals.("hello", getString())`

and they all work fine, but when I'm doing it here the error gets thrown. Could it have something to do with the fact that I'm getting the string from an object? Similar to: `Object.getString()` ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code of the test and at least the signature of the method you're calling. Don't just *vaguely describe* what your code is *like*: show us your code!

Comment: ... a test "returning" something...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure if the `Optional` has a value,

```
Optional<String> string = getString();
assertTrue(optional.isPresent());
assertEquals("hello", optional.get());
```

If you are sure, you can omit the first assert. Optional will throw an exception if it's not present, which will also fail the test.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to compare two different types. Wrap you expected value to Optional `Optional.of(expectedValue)`, or unwrap the actual value `actualValue.get()`

Comment: That's the problem, both of those didn't work. Optional.of(expectedValue) basically made th expected value no longer a string. Instead it became the "optional" type. But i don't want the optional type, i want a string that is optional (I think?). 

Part of the problem is I'm unsure what is being returned by the method i made. It's a String<optional> but I don't know what the difference is between String<optional> vs Optional<optional>. And online resources only give me the latter. I need the former.

Comment: There's no such thing as a String<optional>, only an Optional<String>. Optionals in Java wrap an existing type, but types themselves cannot be optional. If you have an optional, you need to unwrap it to get the actual value it contains, just as Vitalli suggested here.

Comment: Please, provide the code of your test and the method signature you are testing

Comment: I found a solution, although it's not the most clean. Your actualValue.get() didn't work for me since .get() wasn't a function. As in, it couldn't be found and autocomplete didn't work. I was able to turn the actual value into an optional then back into string and it worked, although im betting that isn't the best way to go about things.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized the problem was I turned a string into an optional due to it possibly being null earlier on in the test. Then I turned it back into a string later because my method needed to return a string.

So the value was a string -> optional -> string. My expected needed to mirror that, so my assertion came out to this:
`assertEquals(Optional.of("4.0000").toString(), ACTUALRESULT);`

`"4.0000"` is a string, which gets turned into an optional with the `Optional.of()` method. Then it gets turned back into a string with `toString()`.

Comment: Optional.of("4.0000").toString() will return the string "Optional[4.0000]"... are you certain that's what you want? If not, you should really be using the .get() method, which returns the value contained within the optional.